# How to create a disk image from the command line

Tags: disk-utility

Currently part of my build process is as follows;

- Start Utilities/Disk Utility
- Select New Image
- Set Save As to widget
- Set Name to widget
- Set Size to custom size 50 mb
- Set Format Mac OS Extended

but is it possible to do all this from the command line ?

Answer (score 21):

You can do this with the [hdiutil](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/hdiutil) tool. The appropriate configuration in your case would be:

```
hdiutil create -size 50m -fs HFS+ -volname Widget /path/to/save/widget.dmg
```

Obviously change the "Widget" and path to whatever you need.

A few additional options that may be useful:

- `-srcfolder /path/to/source` This will create the disk image with the data in the specified folder as the contents.
- `-megabytes 50` used instead of `-size 50m`. This will use binary sized megabytes (2^20 bytes) instead of decimal (10^6 bytes).
- `-srcdevice /dev/diskXsY` This  is like `srcfolder`, but makes a block-based copy from another device, like a hard drive partition or DVD. Useful for making clones and images of install disks, etc.

Comment: The link is dead, here's an updated link: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html

Comment: The updated link is now dead. Here's an archived version: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hdiutil.1.html

Answer (score 3):

I made a little bash script to automate a disc image creation.

It creates a temporary directory to store all needed files then export it in a new DMG file. Temporary directory is then deleted.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Create .dmg file for macOS

# Adapt these variables to your needs
APP_VERS="1.0"
DMG_NAME="MyApp_v${APP_VERS}_macos"
OUTPUT_DMG_DIR="path_to_output_dmg_file"
APP_FILE="path_to_my_app/MyApp.app"
OTHER_FILES_TO_INCLUDE="path_to_other_files"


# The directory of the script
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

# The temp directory used, within $DIR
WORK_DIR=`mktemp -d "${DIR}/tmp"`

# Check if tmp dir was created
if [[ ! "${WORK_DIR}" || ! -d "${WORK_DIR}" ]]; then
    echo "Could not create temp dir"
    exit 1
fi

# Function to deletes the temp directory
function cleanup {
    rm -rf "${WORK_DIR}"
    #echo "Deleted temp working directory ${WORK_DIR}"
}

# Register the cleanup function to be called on the EXIT signal
trap cleanup EXIT

# Copy application on temp dir
cp -R "${APP_FILE}" "${WORK_DIR}"
# Copy other files without hidden files
rsync -a --exclude=".*" "${OTHER_FILES_TO_INCLUDE}" "${WORK_DIR}"

# Create .dmg
hdiutil create -volname "${DMG_NAME}" -srcfolder "${WORK_DIR}" -ov -format UDZO "${OUTPUT_DMG_DIR}/${DMG_NAME}.dmg"
```

Comment: For more information about temporary directory creation : it comes from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34676160/6415465